# Is it possible to get the target css property value during a css3 transition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I've two divs *positioned absolutly* and I position them relative to each other. When `width` of one is change, then i recalculate and set positions. While I use css3 transition on '`width`' property, when i try to get '`width`' of animated one, it gives me the current value on dom. But i want to get the target value of transition to set positions correctly on begin of transition effect. Is this possible to get the target value via javascript or other ways?

**EDIT**

Below is a jsfiddle demonstrates my issue. It alerts '100px' but I need to get '300px'.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mdbgs/

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us your code ? maybe you should consider creating a sample on jsfiddle to highlight the problem so we can understand your issue and try to help you with it.

Comment: How do you set the width? Is it on "auto" and it automatically expands/shrinks?

Comment: let me try to create a fiddle

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the question. Please check it.

Comment: If you set it like that, I don't see the problem. I mean, why do you need to read it from the dom if you hardcode it in the javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/Mdbgs/1/

Comment: this is happen becuase you animation not complete. so try animation complete first then get the value

Comment: @JonasGrumann the stuation is not that clear. I've UI controls written in javascript that communicates each other via an event mechanism, like .Net or Java. So, if it can be done without any parameter deifiniton, that should be good. Else, I should create an event argument object to pass the real width value, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: You want to know the target value, when the transition starts? But why, if it is anything else then "auto" you already know it. Don't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [`.css('width')`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is calling `getComputedStyle` on the element, which does return the transitioning value. If you did directly access the style, you would get what you just had set:

```
document.getElementById('transition_div').style.width
$('#transition_div').prop('style').width
$('#transition_div')[0].style.width
```

([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdbgs/3/))

Comment: You are awesome man, that is what i was asking about. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: is it possible somehow get value of calculated css property? I mean when is not specified in styles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975412/is-it-possible-to-get-the-target-calculated-css-property-value-during-a-css3-tra

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `transitionend` event: ([see for equivalent prefixed vendor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility))

```
$('#transition_div').css('width', 300).on("transitionend", function () {
    alert($(this).css('width'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdbgs/2/)

Comment: I didn't know about that event, thak you for answer. But actaully I need to get the value on start of the transition. Is there any legal or illegal way to do this?

Comment: So see @JonasGrumann comments, as i don't understand your issue either. Because, if you animate the DIV to a specific value, then you know the value.

Comment: I have the same problem and I would probably have demonstrated the same way.  What happens for me is that in the real code the part which is doing the animation and the part which is checking are in completely different places.  The part where I need to read the value is actually in my tests.