# Is it possible to get the target calculated css property value during a css3 transition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Is it possible to get the target (final) calculated css property value during a css3 transition in Javascript?

I found this answer:
[Is it possible to get the target css property value during a css3 transition in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486458/is-it-possible-to-get-the-target-css-property-value-during-a-css3-transition-in)

So, I can get it as

```
document.getElementById('transition_div').style.width
```

BUT this works only when target css property is specified in css. I need get target property value which is calculated dynamicaly - not specified in CSS.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell-1">CELL 1</td>
        <td id="cell-2">CELL 2</td>
        <td id="cell-3">CELL 3 some text</td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function() { //let's browser draw initial state
    document.getElementById("cell-1").style["min-width"] = "300px"; //resize one of cells

    setTimeout(function() {
        //NOW, a second later, transition is in progress

        //HOW to get target width of #cell-3 ????

    }, 1000);

}, 0);
```

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/R62yk/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all CSS rules that apply to an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle). Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { //let's browser draw initial state
    document.getElementById("cell-1").style["min-width"] = "300px"; //resize one of cells

    setTimeout(function() {
        //NOW, a second later, transition is in progress

        //HOW to get target width of #cell-3 ????
        var cell = document.getElementById("cell-3"),
            width = getComputedStyle(cell,null).getPropertyValue("width");
        // computed width is 206px
    }, 1000);

}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But computed style provide actual value, not target value

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, what do you mean by "target value" exactly?

Comment: @Simone the target value is the final value of the transition, whereas when you call `getComputedStyle` you get the current interpolated value.